# breeze-client - any way to consume metadata from Web API?

Tags: breeze

Hi I created a method on my Web API Controller that successfully returns the metadata as string. I am just wondering if there is a clever way of generating entities at runtime instead of generating entities in TS client side beforehand?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return this.dataContext.Metadata();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of generating the TypeScript entities beforehand is so that you have types and intellisense to help you write your code correctly.

But of course the EntityManager can create entities on the fly from the metadata; you just need to know the name of the EntityType:

```js
let cust = manager.createEntity("Customer");
```

And you can query entities from the server without pre-generated classes:

```js
const query = new EntityQuery('Customers').where('lastName', 'startsWith', 'C');
manager.executeQuery(query).then(qr => {
  let customers = qr.results;
  // do something with customers...
});
```

In the early days of Breeze, we always loaded the metadata from the server on-the-fly, usually as the app was starting up.

These days, I code in TypeScript, and I find it very helpful to have the metadata and classes pre-generated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The above method is needed or at least one called Metadata of type HTTP GET. the data service in breeze-client needs to have the property hasServerMetadata to false and the magic happens.